# Splitting a string with multiple delimiters and conditions

Tags: python, regex, parsing, split

I have a string from log file which has multiple delimiter to make it  sequence.

Full string `field1.field2.field3/field4/field5|field6|field7//|field8..`

Delimited by `.`  `field1.field2.field3`

Delimited by `/`  `/field4/field5`

Delimited by `|`. But, `"/"` and `"."` are not delimiter in this portion of string
`|field6|field7//|field8..`

Currently, I am parsing like below,

```
x
Out[64]: 'field1.field2.field3/field4/field5|field6|field7//|field8..'

y= x.split("|")
y
Out[66]: ['field1.field2.field3/field4/field5', 'field6', 'field7//', 'field8..']

z = y[0].split("/")
z
Out[68]: ['field1.field2.field3', 'field4', 'field5']

i = z[0].split(".")
i
Out[70]: ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']


result = i+z[1:]+y[1:]
result
Out[79]: 
['field1',
 'field2',
 'field3',
 'field4',
 'field5',
 'field6',
 'field7//',
 'field8..']
```

I think its very ineffecient way of parsing. Appreciate some suggestion to make it better.

I cannot have all three delimiters `[|\.]` to delimit the attribute in string without condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.split`

```
re.split(r'[./|]', x)
```

or

```
re.split(r'\b[./]\b|\|', x)
```

- `\b[./]\b` matches all the dots or forward slashes which are preceded and followed by word characters.
- `|` OR
- `\|` Matches all pipe chars.
- `re.split` would do splitting according to the matched chars.

**OR**

```
>>> s = "field1.field2.field3/field4/field5|field6|field7//|field8.."
>>> re.split(r'(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)|(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)|(?<!\|)\|(?!\|)', s)
['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5', 'field6', 'field7//', 'field8..']
```

Comment: but that will delimit this field `'field7//', 'field8..'`

Comment: Awesome it works could you help me understand this regex `'\b[./]\b|\|'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, your explanation of `\b[./]\b|\|` is lacking.  How do you know non-delimiter dots or slashes will never appear between word characters, like `field.8..`?  Or that tokens won't contain other non-word characters, like `+field2` or `"field3"`?